# Netduino communication with PC

Tags: c#, serial-port, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I am new to netduino so I have a simple question (or, it should be simple).
What I want to do is to send an integer (string)  via rs232 from my winform app to my netduino plus 2, and then, my netduino should read that integer and blink an onboard led that many times.

I have read online tutorial on that topic and found some examples that should provide communication between my PC and Netduino.

Yes, I did got an echo from it. I am getting an echo even if I disconnect my netduino and hide it in my pocket :). 
So much for my understanding of that gadget.

How can I send an info to my Netduino via rs232 cabel that he can read, understand and act accordingly?

There is a code straight from the the web:

For NETDUINO:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.SPOT;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;
using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware;
using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware.Netduino;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace NetduinoApplication1
{
public class Program
{
    static SerialPort serial;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // initialize the serial port for COM1 (using D0 & D1)
        serial = new SerialPort(SerialPorts.COM1, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        // open the serial-port, so we can send & receive data
        serial.Open();
        // add an event-handler for handling incoming data
        serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
        OutputPort led = new OutputPort(Pins.ONBOARD_LED, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            led.Write(true); // turn on the LED
            Thread.Sleep(250); // sleep for 250ms
            led.Write(false); // turn off the LED
            Thread.Sleep(250); // sleep for 250ms

        }

        // wait forever...
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    static void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        // create a single byte array
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];

        // as long as there is data waiting to be read
        while (serial.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // read a single byte
            serial.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            // send the same byte back

            serial.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            OutputPort led1 = new OutputPort(Pins.ONBOARD_LED, false);
            led1.Write(true); // turn on the LED
            Thread.Sleep(250); // sleep for 250ms
            led1.Write(false); // turn off the LED
            Thread.Sleep(250); // sleep for 250ms

        }

    }

}
}
```

And the code for my console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleRSS
{
class Program
{
    static SerialPort serial;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // provide some usage information
        System.Console.WriteLine("enter some text and hit ENTER.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("enter 'x' and hit ENTER to exit.");
        System.Console.WriteLine();

        // initialize the serial port for COM3 (could be other port, depends on system)
        serial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        // open the serial-port, so we can send & receive data
        serial.Open();
        // add an event-handler for handling incoming data
        serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);

        // this will hold each line entered
        string line = string.Empty;

        // as long as an x is not entered
        while (line.ToLowerInvariant() != "x")
        {
            // read a single line from the console
            line = System.Console.ReadLine();

            // convert the line to bytes
            byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);

            // send the bytes over the serial-port
            serial.Write(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
        }
    }
    static void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // wait a little for the buffer to fill
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        // create an array for the incoming bytes
        byte[] bytes = new byte[serial.BytesToRead];
        // read the bytes
        serial.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        // convert the bytes into a string
        string line = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        // write the received bytes, as a string, to the console
        System.Console.WriteLine("echo: " + line);
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: can you show some code of something you have tried? was this the example you tried? http://www.instructables.com/id/Serial-Port-Programming-With-NET/

Comment: Maybe you and the author of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623915/how-to-send-a-signal-to-run-a-machine-using-netduino should talk :) Pretty similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you are actually getting with this? Your code at first glance looks correct.

I would try checking your hardware first, so is the usb cable actually set as COM 1 in device manager on your pc? Is the cable connected to the correct ports in the netduino?